# How can I register a user with Firebase

Tags: jquery, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDhPhJnkmvqL59Dlt_GugIT7IDHaRjOd8g",
authDomain: "ergasia-c04c3.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://ergasia-c04c3.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "ergasia-c04c3",
storageBucket: "ergasia-c04c3.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "615312447322"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script>
$("#register-submit").click(function() {

  var email = $("#email").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).catch(function(error) {

  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code ;
  var errorMessage = error.message ;

  if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
    alert('The password is too weak.');
 } else {
    alert(errorMessage);
  }
  console.log(error);
});
});
```

I've got these scripts and I'm trying to connect my HTML web page with Firebase but when I try to register, nothing happens to Firebase which means that there is a problem on my code or at connection between my webpage and Firebase. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Nothing happens? As in, no error?

Comment: nothing at all..

Comment: Can you provide your HTML and the rest of the js? It could be that your form is submitting and redirecting the page, not giving enough type for createUserWithEmailAndPassword to complete.